Prefiltering Fetchxml SSRS
I am trying to get the guid in the dataset and use that value in multiple datasets using fetchxml in SSRS.  I would like to display the related records from each entity in a table within the report.  Would anyone be able to assist me with this issue? Thank you.
Tried adding prefilter parameter and pass it into another dataset.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the Help center, take a Tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a Minimal, Reproducible Example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.
